# GoDaddy's SMTP server to send email Error

Tags: c#, email

I want to send email with my web application. It is published on rackspace dedicated server but I'm using GoDaddy's SMTP server to send email.

The fault I'm getting is:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: sorry, relaying denied from your location [xx.xx.xxx.xx] (#5.7.1)

This is my code

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25); 
string to ="rpanchal@itaxsmart.com"; 
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("EmailId@domain.com","**");

MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("myEmailId@domain.com", "CompanyName"); 
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(); 
message.From = fromAddress; 
message.To.Add(to); 
message.Body = "This is Test message";
message.Subject = "hi";

client.Send(message); message.Dispose(); return "Email Send";
```

Should I do any configuration on dedicated server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you testing locally? If yes, then your SMTP server may not allow relaying. Do not worry when you will deploy the application there won't be any problem.

Comment: thanks for Replay but i am not Testing Locally i have Published and Testing it but i published it on Windows server and my host for email in On godeady that is relay-hosting.secureserver.net

Comment: Are you hosting on godaddy too? If not, then explain your situation to godaddy, they only would be able to help you.

Comment: no i m not hosting on Godaddy. can you Tell me what is alternet solution or can we create our own SMTP for Sending email on windows server of Yes then how??

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting with RackSpace you should use the SMTP RackSpace recommends for sending from their servers. Unfortunately, you can only use relay-hosting.secureserver.net if you are sending from go Daddy Shared or 4GH hosting.

Comment: Thank you For Reply.What Should i set on my dedicated server ?  i want to send email via smtp .

Answer (score 0):

Start trying to change your port 465 instead 25.

Or remember Relay-hosting is very limited to 250 emails per day and not accept remote connections so easy. Check if you can use SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

That is so simple:

You must focus on smtp host, port, ssl...
Change smtp host to: **relay-hosting.secureserver.net**
And **DELETE** **port** and **ssl**, thats all...
**Do not use smtp port and smtp ssl true or false**

```
    var fromAddress = "mailfrom@yourdomain";
    // any address where the email will be sending
    var toAddress = "mailto@yourdomain";
    //Password of your mail address
    const string fromPassword = "******";
    // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
    string subject = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    string body = "From: " + TextBox2.Text + "\n";
    body += "Email: " + TextBox3.Text + "\n";
    body += "Subject: " + TextBox4.Text + "\n";
    body += "Message: \n" + TextBox5.Text + "\n";
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
**//Warning Delete =>//smtp.Port = 80;**
**//Warning Delete =>//smtp.EnableSsl = false;**
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
```